# Talking about Japanese food, why can 焼{や}き be as either a suffix or a prefix?

Tags: grammar

## 焼き as a prefix

- 焼{や}きそば
- 焼{や}き鳥{とり}
- 焼{や}き肉{にく}
- 焼{や}き飯{めし}

## 焼き as suffix

- たこ焼{や}き
- お好{この}み焼{や}き
- 卵{たまご}焼{や}き

## Questions

Talking about Japanese food, why can 焼{や}き be as either a suffix or a prefix? It seems to me there is no inconsistency here. Which one is actually the correct one? As a prefix or as a suffix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

焼き as a prefix is used to describe how the ingredient was prepared. Corresponding to English -ed verb, like *roasted beef*.

焼き as a suffix is more like a dish proper name. It is used as a noun to describe the result of processing. Corresponding to English *garlic beef pot roast*.

焼きas a suffix doesn't really have to be prepared using the other part of the word. Like お好み is not grilled, nor Is a sea bream a component of  たい焼き.

Comment: [目からうろこ](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E9%B1%97%E3%81%8C%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8B)でした。確かに「広島焼き」が「焼き広島」だったらすごく変…（笑）